# Can't send data from API to AJAX using POST method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am having very weird problem. My ajax request, returns only the strings without the actual values in it / except where the class ID is, only there it retrieves the postID /.
I am not sure where the problem is but here is my code:

JQUERY:

```
var roomID = jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('id');
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/wp-json/api/hotelRooms',
            data: {
                'post_id':roomID
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            jQuery(".rooms-popups-container").empty();
            jQuery(".rooms-popups-container").append(data);
            console.log(data);
            },
            error: function hotelRooms(data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
```

PHP: / not posting all the code just small part of it

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function (){
    register_rest_route( 'api', '/hotelRooms', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'hotelRooms',
    ));
});

function hotelRooms($returndata){
  $postID = $_POST['post_id'];
  $posttitle = get_the_title($postID);
  $postcontent = get_post_field('post_content', $postID);
  $galleries = get_post_meta( $postID, '_hb_gallery', true );
  $returndata = "";
  $returndata .= '<div class="hb_single_room room-popup" id="popup-room-'.$postID.'">
      <div class="summary entry-summary">
          <div class="title">
              <h4>
                  <a href="#">'. $posttitle .'</a>
                  <img class="close-room-popup" room_id="'.$postID.'" alt="x" src="https://www.micasas.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/x.png">
              </h4>
          </div>';
  return $returndata;
}
```

In POSTMAN it returns the actual values and everything i need -> http://prntscr.com/me517n but in the Jquery returns only part of the information: http://prntscr.com/me51e0

Comment: It looks like your `$posttitle, $postcontent, ...` are empty, how does `get_the_title(), ...` fonctions work ?

Comment: @RomainB. If they are empty they won't be working on the postman, would they? 
get_the_title get's the title by ID, which i have from variable roomID in JS..

Comment: @milen Have you checked if you really have the roomID in JS. As the PHP code works fine via Postman, it most probably is the JS.

Comment: @BilalAkbar yes it is, http://prntscr.com/me51e0 from this screenshot you can see that it get's the correct ID of product / it changes when different links are clicked i tested it /

Comment: @milen you should try to call `get_the_title()` and other fonctions with a static value for `$postID` in your php first (4464 for exemple) and start debugging your fonctions from that. Maybe your call is a bit different from Postman

Comment: @RomainB. lol yes actually when i pass a static value it works, hmm why is it then working in the Postman.. this is what is confusing me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i get it

You are currently sending `room-<id>` from your js instead of `<id>` that's why your functions are returning empty values.
You can use something like the following in `hotelRooms()`

```
$postID = explode("room-",$_POST['post_id'])[1];
```

Comment: Now it works. Lol, didn't even consider that as an option... Thanks a lot man!!